# PRODSECBUG-2198 - Installation Steps

Tags: magento2, patches

I am having a Magento 2.2.6 site. I want to install PRODSECBUG-2198 patch.

Little bit confusing with the flow. Can anyone guide me?

Magento Decribed the Patch like this:

> This patch provides protection against the SQL injection vulnerability
>   described under PRODSECBUG-2198 [here](https://magento.com/security/patches/magento-2.3.1-2.2.8-and-2.1.17-security-update). To quickly protect your
>   store from this vulnerability only, install this patch. However, to
>   apply protection against this vulnerability and others, you must apply
>   the 2.3.1, 2.2.8, or 2.1.17 patch code. We strongly suggest that you
>   install these full patches as soon as you can

Here what they are supposed to mean for

> you must apply the 2.3.1, 2.2.8, or 2.1.17 patch code. We strongly
>   suggest that you install these full patches as soon as you can

Comment: how to Remove the a/ and b/ before the path name magento patch?

Comment: @Fousseinikonate While edit the patch file before move in, you can see the Path file mentioned in the Patch with a/ and b/. You just remove the letters in it. and upload the Patch to server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.Download the composer patch for Magento 2.2 version `PRODSECBUG-2198-2.2-CE.composer.patch`.

2.Remove the a/ and b/ before the path name.

3.Move the patch file to your Magento root and execute patch -p0 < PRODSECBUG-2198-2.2-CE.composer.patch

The patch has very critical fixes. To get the other Magento bugs fixed do update to the latest version.

Comment: what does this means ? you must apply the 2.3.1, 2.2.8, or 2.1.17 patch code

Comment: There are 3 patch files for 2.1, 2.2, and 2.3 so select the patch for your version and Apply the patch code

Comment: Oh.. Got it.  Thanks. Can you explain to me what is the point of removing a/ and b/ ?

Comment: And Do we need file and db backup before applying it on live?

Comment: I was facing a wrong path error when I executed the patch, so then I found that the a/ and b/ before the path was causing this, Once I removed it was working fine. You no need to backup the database, you can backup these two files vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/ProductFrontendAction/Synchronizer.php and vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php b/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php since the patch changes are for these two files only